# How to detect the object with memory alloc/free error?

Tags: c++, macos, odbc

Mac OS X.
I run a app, which load a odbc driver. I see in the system.log the message:

> malloc: *** error for object incorrect checksum for freed object -
>   object ххх was probably modified after being freed

Also, I have the c++ source codes of this driver but do not see the place where is the problem with malloc/free.

How I can detect and localize what is the object xxx?

Comment: First of all do a code-review of you *own* code. Do you have pointers? Do you have arrays? Do you have vectors? Do you have dynamic allocated "arrays"? If the answer to *any* of those questions is "yes" then check how you use the pointers, arrays, vectors etc. Chances are that you go out of bounds of dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: As a second option, use tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to debug memory allocations and writes. If you build your application with debug information then Valgrind can show you the exact file and line where you go out of bounds or do other bad things with memory and pointers.

Comment: Third option, build with lots and lots of warnings enabled. This should really be the *first* option, and the third be *static analysis tools* (also known as *linters*) to analyze the code you have. Linters are much better at finding troublesome code than your compiler is.

Comment: And on an unrelated note, please take care of your terminology: "Localize" means something very different from "locating", which is what you want to do.

Comment: My odbc driver by fact is the PostgreSQL odbc driver v9

Comment: Which means it probably quite well-tested and not the source of your problem.

Comment: Given a choice between the problem being in the "app" and in an odbc driver, I'd bet it is the "app" at fault.   Drivers tend to be pretty well tested, and if they are used by a lot of people, bugs tend to be found early on.    Whereas app developers tend to be more lax, and more inclined to look for problems outside their own code.

Comment: 2  Some programmer dude: it does not mean, you can check the git log, also i have found some interesting places even in the v10. I use the v 9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macOS / OS X has something called **Guard Malloc**, which contains a number of mechanisms for detecting problems like this (which could be a memory overwrite or a write-after-free) at the point of failure.

All you have to do to make use of it is to set a few environment variables before you launch your app, and make sure that you are running with `libgmalloc.dylib` loaded, for example:

```
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/libgmalloc.dylib MallocGuardEdges=1 myprog
```

Where `MallocGuardEdges` is documented as doing:

> If set, `malloc` adds guard pages before and after large allocations.

The documentation also has this to say (I dimly remember having to do this once):

> To enable debugging using Guard Malloc, configure your project to run with Guard Malloc in the Xcode Scheme Editor.

So that would avoid the need for the `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` trick.

Full details [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html).

Comment: Thanks! I have run the app, it created the log file. But when I open it I see the information but cannot interpret it. How to understand the log file?Any tools?

Comment: I don't actually know, my code never crashes :)  Can you debug your app in Xcode with Guard Malloc enabled?  Then you have a chance of catching the problem at the point of failure.   More details behind that link.

Comment: I run the Java app, which forks other (c++) process which loads odbc driver(c++ *.so file). It has a problems with double free of the same object.  I need to catch the approx. place where it is incorrect free call..

Comment: That sounds like a really thorny problem.  Who supplied these pieces of sofrware, can you turn to them for help?

Comment: No, I cannot, this odbc driver is my code (it is modified postgresql odbc), but the app-caller is not. I am sure that app crashes because of odbc driver has incorrect malloc/free calls

Comment: Yes, I do. But I build odbc via Make

Comment: OK, let me think about this.  It might be a couple of days (and I'm not certain there's anything I can do, but I will get back to you).

Comment: Ok Paul, thanx.